# Why does Exit code give a ValueError?

Tags: python, valueerror

**Here's the code:**

```
print('Type something you idiot:')
while True:
    spam = str(input())
    if spam == '1':
        print('Hello')
    elif spam == '2':
        print('Howdy')
    elif int(spam) > 2 and int(spam) > 1:
        print('Greetings!')
    elif str(spam) == 'exit':
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print('Type a positive # bruh')
    print('Type again you dumdum:')
```

**Here's the error:**

```
exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'exit'

[Program finished]
```

**Other stuff:**

I tried googling that last error line but it seemed unrelated to my problem, something about float and all.
I want the program to exit when I type exit but I get that error.
All the other things seem to be working (1, 2, 3, -1)

Another thing that isn't working is typing something other than "exit". I get the same error message.
Spent a lot of time trying to fix it to no avail.
Please help, thank you.

Comment: `elif int(spam) > 2 and int(spam) > 1:` will attempt to convert `spam` to `int`. `spam` is equal to `'exit'`, and thus cannot be converted to an integer

Comment: also, if `int(spam) > 2` then certainly `int(spam) > 1`, so the condition `int(spam) > 2 and int(spam) > 1` can be simplified to `int(spam) > 2`

Comment: Pydroid makes this a bit more difficult. Normally the traceback would show you the line where the error occurred.

Comment: BTW, `input()` returns a string, you don't need to convert it in `str(input())`, and you definitely don't need to convert it again in `str(spam) == 'exit'`.

Comment: Lol I'm such an idiot, thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare integers to strings. So check if the string is an integer before comparing:

```
print('Type something you idiot:')
while True:
    spam = str(input())
    if spam == '1':
        print('Hello')
    elif spam == '2':
        print('Howdy')
    elif spam.isdigit() and int(spam) > 1:
        print('Greetings!')
    elif str(spam) == 'exit':
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print('Type a positive # bruh')
    print('Type again you dumdum:')
```

This will stop it falling over if something other than a number or "exit" is entered.

Comment: spam.isdigit() is such a nice function, thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

When you type `'exit'` the condition for the third clause in your `if` statement is evaluated. That is, `int(spam) > 2 and int(spam) > 1`. But if `spam = 'exit'`, then `spam` cannot be converted to an `int`, hence the error.

Reordering your clauses in your `if` statement is the easiest solution.

```
print('Type something you idiot:')
while True:
    spam = str(input())
    if spam == '1':
        print('Hello')
    elif spam == '2':
        print('Howdy')
    elif str(spam) == 'exit':
        sys.exit()
    elif int(spam) > 2 and int(spam) > 1:
        print('Greetings!')
    else:
        print('Type a positive # bruh')
    print('Type again you dumdum:')
```

Now, `int(spam) > 2 and int(spam) > 1` is only evaluated if `str(spam) != 'exit'` which is fine for the (limited) inputs you expect.

Comment: Ah, I made a textbook mistake huh. Had read about the rearranging error in Automate The Boring Stuff book and ended up making the same mistake. It was a good learning opportunity though. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned L.Grozinger the "exit match" position is important.

You may also add `ValueError` exception try/catch to fix wrong user input...

```
import sys

print('Type something you idiot:')
while True:
    spam = str(input())
    print(spam)
    try:
        if spam == '1':
            print('Hello')
        elif spam == '2':
            print('Howdy')
        elif spam == "exit":
            sys.exit()
        elif int(spam) > 2 and int(spam) > 1:
            print('Greetings!')

    except ValueError:
        print('Type again you dumdum:')
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. That 'except' code seems handy, just learnt about it.